# how to close a form (created by code)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i am creating a form by codes.

i am using this code

```
Dim frmNew As New Form2
    If frmNew.ShowInTaskbar = True Then
        frmNew.Close()
    End If
    Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    frmNew.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    frmNew.Name = b.Name
    frmNew.Text = b.Text
    Try
        frmNew.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

i have a design in my form2 so this is the form that im using in the declaration of frmnew
after clicking the button it shows my new form
but when i click again the button, it generates a new form the same in the first one.
i want to close first the form
before generating a new form.

i am using this code in my Multiple user LAN CHAT.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make your frmNew variable global, and before generating new form try to close the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find if another instance of the same form is currently open, you could search the collection [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and check if it contains a form with the same name of your Form2. Of course you should avoid to have two unrelated forms with the same name.

```
Dim k = Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form).Where(Function (x) x.Name = "yourFormName").SingleOrDefault() 

if k IsNot Nothing Then
   k.Close()
End If

Dim frmNew As Form2
frmNew = new Form2
Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
frmNew.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
frmNew.Name = b.Name
frmNew.Text = b.Text

Try
    frmNew.Show()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

This approach avoids a global variable to keep track of the previous instance.

After a quick check I think that the search code could be reduced to

```
Dim k = Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form2).SingleOrDefault()
```

And this will avoid also a possible name conflict with an unrelated form with the same name

Comment: hello mr steve. you got what i really want.. thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `frmNew` globally inside you class. This has the advantage that you don't have to worry about closing other forms at all.

So, declare it globally (outside of any method):

```
Dim frmNew as Form2
```

And inside your method:

```
If frmNew IsNot Nothing Then
    frmNew.Close()
frmNew = New Form2
Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
frmNew.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
frmNew.Name = b.Name
frmNew.Text = b.Text
Try
    frmNew.Show()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Now each time the method is called, the same `frmNew` will be (re-)initialized, i.e. you're only working with a single Form2 at all times.

Comment: But the requirement of question is not satisfied

Comment: hello thanks for the answer mr john willemse
i declared already my frmnew globally still 
it opens a new form another form another form when i click my button =(

Comment: Because only variable gets initialized every time, form will not close automatically.

Comment: thanks for this sir john willemse
 mr steve's codes got what i really need.
you answered my question correctly 
but sir steve gets what i really need for my application 
thanks MR! 
i appreciate all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

Global declaration variable, inside class

```
Dim frmNew as New Form2
```

And inside your method:

```
If frmNew.ShowInTaskbar = True Then
    frmNew.Close()
End If
frmNew = New Form2
Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
frmNew.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
frmNew.Name = b.Name
frmNew.Text = b.Text
Try
    frmNew.Show()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```